# Botón Parar Scroll Automático

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hola me gustaría poder hacer que el `id="botonstop"` parase la función desencadenada por el `id="boton"` que en este caso es un scroll automático. También me gustaría que pudiese ser compatible con que el scroll automático se activase nada más cargar la página.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#boton").click(function(event){ 
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: '15000px' }, 10000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="boton" href="#bottom" style="position:fixed;">start scrolling</a>
<a id="botonstop" href="#bottom" style="position:fixed; margin-top:30px;">stop scrolling</a>

<div id="relleno" style="height:15000px; width:500px; background:green;">

<h2 id="bottom">bottom of page</h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/). Mira los cambios que realice, quite el `href` del `a` que invoca el stop

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#boton").click(function(event){ 
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: '15000px' }, 10000);
  });
  $("#botonstop").click(function(event){ 
    $("html, body").stop();
  });
});
```

```css
#botonstop {cursor:pointer; text-decoration: underline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="boton" href="#bottom" style="position:fixed;">start scrolling</a>
<a id="botonstop"  style="position:fixed; margin-top:30px;">stop scrolling</a>

<div id="relleno" style="height:15000px; width:500px; background:green;">

<h2 id="bottom">bottom of page</h2>
```

Comment: No es posible hacerlo como <a> el stop scrolling? no me beneficia que sea un botón

Comment: @IvanSoler Lo actualice con `a` pero fijate que quiete el href, ya que da un bug visual que te manda al top de la pagina, a menos que eso quieras

Comment: Perfecto, con esto que me propones... hay algún modo de hacer que la "flechita" cambie a "manita" sin el href para facilitar la comprensión del usuario?

Comment: Claro css, dame un segundo y edito

Comment: Listo @IvanSoler un link de referencia sobre cursor http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

Comment: Joder, muchas gracias !

Comment: @IvanSoler agregue tambien underline; para las lineas por debajo. En unos 5 minutos voy a borrar estos comentarios para no molestar la lectura a futuros lectores. Siempre que te ayude un placer, happy coding

Comment: Oye! Una duda más, cómo hago para que funcione con tan solo un click (ahora funciona con doble click)

Comment: @IvanSoler en que explorador estas?, a mi me funciona con solo 1 clic

Comment: Es verdad, me pasa lo del doble click al incluirlo dentro de otro documento más complejo en el que la acción convive con otras... veré si puedo solucionarlo por mi cuenta y sino pondré un post. Gracias :)